# Cassandra | CQL | show unconfigured columnfamily error with SELECT QUERY

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cqlsh

I am attempting to create my first table and query it with CQL 3 under Cassandra 1.2.15. My question is that why it show **unconfigured columnfamily** error for my existing table. Some answers for the question is to add double quotes around the table name but do not work for me. Show more information as possible as I can.

```
Connected to dev Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 3.1.8 | Cassandra 1.2.15 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.36.2]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> describe keyspace cb_theme_authors

CREATE KEYSPACE cb_theme_authors WITH replication = {
  'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
  'replication_factor': '1'
};

USE cb_theme_authors;

CREATE TABLE inlucde_authors (
  authorid text,
  themeid text,
  domain text,
  PRIMARY KEY (authorid, themeid, domain)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};

cqlsh>
cqlsh>
cqlsh>
cqlsh> use cb_theme_authors;
cqlsh:cb_theme_authors> SELECT * FROM "include_authors";
Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily include_authors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typo?: CF is created as inlucde_authors but you request include_authors. Read carefully: inLUCde <-> inCLUde